# How to check if the tcp socket is still connected in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, tcp, tcpsocket

I have connected to my server as follows:

```
Socket socket = await Socket.connect('xxx', xxx)
```

But now I want to check if the socket is still connected. It would be even better if I have a listener that tells me when the connection is broken.

Thanks already!
Leonard

Comment: Socket's `listen` method lets you read the data and lets you set an `onDone` method that's called when the socket is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Listen to onDone in its stream

```
socket.stream.listen(
        (dynamic message) {
          debugPrint('message $message');
        },
        onDone: () {
          debugPrint('socket closed');//if closed you will get it here
        },
        onError: (error) {
          debugPrint('error $error');
        },
      );
```